# Get product quantity discount information using runQuery (3DCart Advanced API)

Tags: php, database, soap

I'm trying to get product [quantity discount](https://support.3dcart.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/174) information from the database and form a table using the runQuery method of the 3DCart Advanced API.

Looking at the database diagram which could be downloaded here: [Advanced API Technical Reference](https://support.3dcart.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/459/0/advanced-api-technical-reference) - did not give anything. It seems to me, that they did not include that table in there at all.

Last thing I tried is to get information from the `product` table:

```
<?php

class Data {
  private $db;
  public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new soapclient('http://api.3dcart.com/cart_advanced.asmx?WSDL',array('trace'=>1,'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1));
  }

  public function query($sql = "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM category"){
    $param = array(
      'storeUrl'=>"[URL]",
      'userKey'=>"[KEY]",
      'sqlStatement'=>$sql
    );
    $result = $this->db->runQuery($param);
    $match = $result->runQueryResult->any;
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($match);
    return $sxe->runQueryRecord;
  }
}

$db = new Data();
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE catalogid = 124");
var_dump($query);

?>
```

... hoping that the data needed will be there, but it was not.

P.S. There is no 3DCart tag, so I hope this question will reach specialists, who have knowledge of 3DCart's API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from 3DCart support:

> The quantity discounts are stored in the 'pricing' table where 'pricing.prod_id' has a foreign key relationship to 'products.catalogid'.

Now everything works. Thanks.

```
<?php

$params = array(
  'storeUrl' => "[URL]",
  'userKey' => "[KEY]"
);
$db =  new soapclient('http://api.3dcart.com/cart_advanced.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));

// Retrive product list
$result = $db->runQuery($params + array(
  'sqlStatement' => "SELECT pricing.*, products.name, products.price FROM pricing LEFT JOIN products ON pricing.prod_id = products.catalogid WHERE pricing.price_level = 1"
));
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($result->runQueryResult->any);

$products = array(); // Use for rows
$discounts = array(); // Use for columns
if (!empty($sxe->runQueryRecord)) {
  foreach ($sxe->runQueryRecord as $record) {
    $products[(int) $record->prod_id]['name'] = (string) $record->name;
    $products[(int) $record->prod_id]['price'] = (string) $record->price;
    $products[(int) $record->prod_id]['pricing'][(string) $record->lowbound ."|". (string) $record->upbound] = (string) $record->percentage == "True"
      ? (float) $record->{"products.price"} - ( (float) $record->{"products.price"} / 100 ) * (float) $record->{"pricing.price"}
      : (float) $record->{"products.price"} - (float) $record->{"pricing.price"};

    $discounts[(string) $record->lowbound ."|". (string) $record->upbound] = (string) $record->lowbound ." - ". (string) $record->upbound;
  }
}

var_dump($products);
var_dump($discounts);

?>
```